# Matlab: How to remove loops from given code

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I need  to implement the following loop without using loops.
*A  Typical Example is*
 `size(pos)  = [480 640 200 2]`.

**NOTE : -** It is guaranteed that the values of pos(:,:,:,1) are in range `1:size(pos,2)` while values of pos(:,:,:,2) are in range `1:size(pos,1)`

```
[height width N  ~] = size(pos); 
output = uint8(zeros(height,width,0));
for k =1:N
     prediction = uint8(zeros(height,width)); 
     for i =1:height
        for j =1:width
            a = pos(i,j,k,2);
            b = pos(i,j,k,1);
            int_ = intensity(i,j,k); %// intensity is a height x width x N , uint8 matrix which has intensity values of an rgb image sequence of size height x width and length N
            prediction(a,b) = int_;
        end
    end
output = cat(3,output,prediction);
end
```

**EDIT :-**

As Luis mentioned it is possible that `pos` has repeated values so `prediction(a,b) = int_` may be overwritten . In that case I would like to have a way to put all the repeated values instead of overwriting and just keeping the last one.

AN example is let say pos has following values `pos(12,12,3,1) = 12; pos(12,12,3,2) = 12; pos(13,13,3,1) = 12; pos(13,13,3,2) = 12; intensity(12,12,3) = 45 ; intensity(13,13,3) = 58`
Then In this code `predicted(12,12)` will be assigned  value `58` but I would like it to be assigned as `some scalar value between 45 and 58` .

Please keep in mind that `intensity is a height x width x N , uint8 matrix which has intensity values of an rgb image sequence of size height x width and length N`

Comment: Is it possible that `pos` has repeated values, and thus `prediction(a,b) = int_;` overwrites sometimes?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes it is possible. And I would appreciate If you could tell  me a method such that I am able to incorporate all the repeated values at a particular position  `a , b` into a single value, not just overwrite and keep the last value. And values of intensity matrix are intensity values of a rgb image.

Comment: To do that you would need a cell array, with a vector stored at each cell; and the problem would be quite different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to the original question: assignment overwrites values**

The fact that values can be overwritten makes this tricky, because the order of the assignments is then crucial. To maintain the same order of assignments that you use in your loop, we work with size `[width height N]` (not `[height width N]`), and then `permute` back:

```
sub3 = reshape(kron(1:N,ones(1,height*width)), [width height N]);
pos = permute(pos, [2 1 3 4]);
ind = sub2ind([width height N], pos(:,:,:,1),pos(:,:,:,2),sub3); %// linear index
output = uint8(zeros(width,height,N)); %// initiallize
output(ind) = permute(intensity, [2 1 3]); %// assign (with overwriting)
output = permute(output, [2 1 3]); %// put back into desired shape
pos = permute(pos, [2 1 3 4]);
```

**Answer to edited question: average/keep all values at coindicent position**

In this case order of assignment is not important, so no need to permute dimensions. Use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to average all values coresponding to the same position:

```
sub3 = reshape(kron(1:N,ones(1,height*width)), [height width N]);
ind = sub2ind([height width N], pos(:,:,:,2),pos(:,:,:,1),sub3); %// linear index
output = accumarray(ind(:), double(intensity(:)), [height*width*N, 1], @mean);
output = reshape(output, [height width N]);
```

Or, if you want to keep all values for each position, just modify the `accumarray` line with a custom anonymous function that returns all values:

```
sub3 = reshape(kron(1:N,ones(1,height*width)), [height width N]);
ind = sub2ind([height width N], pos(:,:,:,2),pos(:,:,:,1),sub3); %// linear index
output = accumarray(ind(:), double(intensity(:)), [height*width*N, 1], @(x) {x});
output = reshape(output, [height width N]);
```

In the latter case `output` will be a cell array such that each cell contains a vector with all values corresponding to that position.

Comment: I got this error `??? Error using ==> sub2ind at 52
The subscripts vectors must all be of the same size.

Error in ==> write_image_via_pos_using_tracked_intensity at 24
*line 24 is:* ind = sub2ind([width height N], pos(:,:,:,1),pos(:,:,:,2),sub3); %// linear index`

It may be due to ` size(sub3) == [ width height N] `` while `size(pos(:,:,:,1) == [height width N]` .

Comment: It worked thanks, execution time reduced from `60.89 seconds to 2.7 seconds`. Can you give me some pointers to solve the second part(part after the edit).

Comment: See edited question. `accumarray` can do what you want. I'm assuming that you want to average all values at the same position

Comment: Or you can also keep all values instead of just their average